# How do I efficiently pull data from a server several times a second?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, node.js

I have a bidimensional boolean array of 10,000 x 10,000 living on a variable inside a server on Node.js.

This array is continuously evolving and changing randomly, plus the user is able to choose and modify (or only see) a 100 x 100 part of it on the www.example.com:3000 address.

I currently use AJAX calls to get a JSON of this slice of the array however I'm starting to realize that these calls are not fast enough, sometimes calls will just hang-up or will simply never return back especially if there are too many users.

I need to perform around 100 calls per second.

**How do I efficiently pull the slice of the array?**

**Is there any other alternative or should I just try to optimize the AJAX calls?**

Comment: Try using websockets.

Comment: You may want to take a look at Server sent events (send data from the server to the client) or websockets (bidirectional)

Comment: You might be able to reduce the size, by grouping the boolean values into integers, and use a bitmask to get individual booleans. Not sure how to do that in JS, though.

Comment: Take a look at www.socket.io